# Disadvantages of strlen() in Embedded Domain

Tags: c, string, network-programming, embedded

What are the disadvantages of using strlen()?

If sometimes in TCP Communication NULL character comes in string than we find length of string up to only null character.

we cant find actual length of string.

if we make other alternative of this strlen function than its also stops at NULL character. so which method i can use to find out string length in C

Comment: What do you mean by 'actual length of string'?

Comment: In C, a string is by definition terminating at the first NUL character encountered. If not, it is plain data, not a string.

Comment: should we read "embedded" as "non-preemptive multitasking" here ? If so, read my updated answer.

Comment: The problems you describe don't have anything to do with the 'embedded domain' and don't really have anything to do with `strlen()` - the problems you're describing have to do with whether or not you have a clear understanding of the data you're working with. `strlen()` only works with null terminated strings.  If you're working with a different kind of data, you can't use it.

Comment: Very tempted to remove the "embedded" tag here - anyone else agree?

Comment: @Dan: I wouldn't if we have confirmation that having the program staying for "too long" on an operation that was planned to be short is a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

To read from a "TCP Communication" you are probably using `read`. The prototype for `read` is

```
ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte);
```

and the return value is the number of bytes read (even if they are `0`).
So, let's say you're about to read 10 bytes, all of which are 0. You have an array with more than enough to hold all the data

```
int fildes;
char data[1000];
// fildes = TCPConnection
nbytes = read(fildes, data, 1000);
```

Now, by inspecting `nbytes` you know you have read 10 bytes. If you check `data[0]` through `data[9]` you will find they have `0`;

Answer (score 1):

If the runtime library provides [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) and [`strcat()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/), then surely it provides [`strlen()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/).

I suspect you are confusing [NULL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/NULL/), an invalid pointer value, from the ASCII code [NUL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), for a zero character value which indicates the end of string to many C runtime functions.

As such, there is no concern for inserting a NUL value in a string, nor in detecting it.

---

Response to updated question:

Since you seem to be processing binary data, the string functions are not a good fit—unless you can guarantee there are no NULs in the stream.  However, for this reason, most TCP/IP messages use headers with fields containing the number of bytes which follow.

Comment: Please Refer my Updated question

Comment: Because from some where i heard strlen() is not safe in Embedded because it gives length up to NULL character.

Comment: @user1089679 strlen() works with strings. If you're not dealing with strings, it doesn't make sense to use strlen(). Also, what do you mean by "not safe" ? strlen is perfectly safe when you use it correctly, but as with almost any library calls, it can cause problems if you do not use it correctly.

Comment: @nos ya m dealing with String data. and not safe means its given length up to null character, suppose in string we getting null in between string. so its not give actual string

Comment: @user1089679: if it has a NUL byte in the middle, then *it is not a string*. You think it is, but you're wrong. Only the part of it up to the embedded NUL is a string. That's the only "danger" with `strlen` - you might pass into it a pointer to something that you think is a string, but you're wrong.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ok so When i am dealing with String over Socket communication than strlen() is fine?

Comment: @user1089679: depends what you mean by "fine". If the data has all been read, and if the other end of the socket was kind enough to include a NUL byte, then `strlen` will tell you the length of the string, which by definition is the number of bytes before the NUL. That's a lot of trust to put in the person at the other end of the socket, and you also have to make sure you don't call `strlen` after an incomplete read.

Comment: @SteveJessop, Thanks a lot but i am always using strlen after complete reading. than after its fine ?

Comment: @user1089679 Have you read a string ? If so, yes it is fine to use strlen().  Ofcourse, a network is untrusted, so you can not know if you did read a string. How do you know you've read a string ? You walk the bytes you have read and look for a 0 byte. Everything up to that point is a string. There's no reason to use strlen(). And if you're using TCP, you might read more than one string, you might get 3 and a half strings, depending on the protocol and the code you've written, you need to handle that case. TLDR; no, it's not fine to call strlen() on the buffer just after you call read()/recv()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `strlen()` uses a terminating character `\0` aka NUL. Most str* functions do so. There could be a risk that data coming from files/command line/sockets would not contain this character (usually, they won't: they'll be `\n`-terminated), but their size will also be provided by the `read()`/`recv()` function you've used. If that's a concern, you can always use a buffer slightly larger than what declared to those functions, e.g.

```
char mybuf[256+4];
mybuf[256]=0;
int reallen=fgets(mybuf, 256, stdin);
// we've got a 0-terminated string in mybuf.
```

If your data may not contain `\0`, compare `strlen(mybuf)` with `reallen` and terminate the session with an error code if they differ.
If your data may contain `0`, then it should be processed as a buffer and not as a string. Size must be kept aside, and `memcpy` / `memcmp` functions should be used instead of strcpy and strcmp.

Also, your network protocol should be very explicit on whether strings or binary data is expected in different parts of the communication. HTTP is for instance, and it provides many way to tell the actual size of the transmitted payload.

This isn't specific to "embedded" programs, but it has come a major concern in every programs to ensure no remote code/script injection can occur. If by "embedded", you mean you're in a non-preemptive environment and have only limited time available to perform some action ... then yeah, you don't want to end up scanning 2GB of incoming bits for a (never-appearing) `\0`. either the above trick, or strnlen (mentioned in another answer) could be used to ensure this isn't the case.

Comment: Here i am getting data from sockets (TCP)

Comment: ... which shouldn't invalidate whatever is said above. With sockets, you should pay extra care that "some data" may become available at various rate, i.e. if you want to recv(at_most 4KB), the kernel may block until *some* data arrive. If only 2KB arrived, you're served 2KB. Eat them while their hot or wait for more: that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

"Embedded" strikes me as a red herring here.

If you're processing binary data where an embedded NUL might be valid, then you can't expect meaningful results from `strlen`.

If you're processing strings (as that term is defined in C -- a block of non-NUL data terminated by a NUL) then you can use `strlen` just fine.

A system being "embedded" would affect this only to the degree that it might be less common to process strings and more common to process binary data.

Answer (score 1):

it is safer to use strnlen instead of strlen to avoid the problems with strlen.  The strlen problems are present everywhere not just embedded.  Many of the string functions are dangerous because they go forever or until a zero is hit, or like scanf or strtok go until a pattern is hit.

Remember tcp is a stream not a packet, you may have to wait for multiple or many packets and piece together the data before you can attempt to call it a string anyway.  that is assuming the payload is an asciiz string anyway, if raw data then dont use string functions use some other solution.

Comment: ooh. So all this "security/embedded" thing would be linked to the fact that he's in a non-preemptive environment and has only limited time available to perform some action ... and obviously, scanning 2GB of incoming bits for a (never-appearing) `\0` wouldn't be nice.

Comment: and your point is well taken, common tcp protocols dont necessarily terminate with a null but terminate a line with a line feed, so strlen wouldnt be the right function anyway.